# div needs a background to act as a trigger 

Tags: jquery

I have a simple slide show that I am working on from a book (jQuery, novice to ninja)

It all works fine in everything except IE8 (and I am guessing 7)

Its triggered by a div that is placed above the slide show. It has a link in it which is sent off screen. The trigger div has no background (obviously!).

```
#photos {
border: 1px solid #BEBEBE; 
height: 350px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index:1;
width: 350px;
}

#photos ul {
left: 0;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index:2;
top: 0;
width: 1400px;
}

#photos li {
float: left;
}

#trigger {
position:relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 10;
text-indent: -9999px;
height:150px;
width:350px;
display: block;
}
```

Here's the html

```
<div id="photos">
<div id="trigger"><a href="">hi</a></div>
<ul id="photos_inner">
<li>
<img alt="Glendatronix" src="images/clothes001.gif" />
</li>
<li>
<img alt="Glendatronix" src="images/clothes002.gif" />
</li>
<li>
<img alt="Glendatronix" src="images/clothes003.gif" />
</li>
<li>
<img alt="Glendatronix" src="images/clothes004.gif" />
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

And lastly some jQuery - there's more which I'll happily post if anyone wants to see it. I can't even get simple alerts to work in IE8

```
gallery.init = function() {
    $(gallery.trigger)
        .mouseout(function() {alert("hit mouseout")})
        .click(function() {alert("you clikced")})
```

What's weird (to me) is that if I reduce the height of the trigger div, and then give it a background colour it works fine. In other words it seems to need a background colour to take up its sizes???

ANyone got any ideas for what I need to try - don't really want the background colour there obviously

Thanks

E

Here's the rest of the jq. I realise that I might not have put enough in before.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        gallery.trigger = $("#trigger");
        gallery.content = $("#photos_inner");
        gallery.scroll = false;
        gallery.width = 350;
        gallery.innerWidth = gallery.content.width();
        gallery.timer = false;  

        gallery.init();

});

gallery = {};


gallery.offset = function() {
    var left = gallery.content.position().left;
    if (gallery.scroll == '>') {
        if (left < 0) {
            left += gallery.width;
        }
    } else {
        if (left <= 0 && left >= ((gallery.innerWidth * -1) + (gallery.width * 2))) {
        left -= gallery.width;
        }
    }
    return left + "px";
}

gallery.slide = function() {
    if (gallery.timer) {
        clearTimeout(gallery.timer);
    }
    if (gallery.scroll) {
        $(gallery.content)
        .stop(true,true)
        .animate({left: gallery.offset()}, 500);
        gallery.timer = setTimeout(gallery.slide, 1000);
    }
}

gallery.direction = function(e,which) {
    var x = e.pageX - which.offset().left;
    gallery.scroll = (x >= gallery.width / 2) ? ">" : "<";
}

gallery.init = function() {
    $(gallery.trigger)
        .mouseout(function() {alert("hit mouseout")})
        .click(function() {alert("you clikced")})
        .mouseout(function() {gallery.scroll = false;})
        .mousemove(function(e) {gallery.direction(e,gallery.trigger);})
        .mouseover(function(e) {
        gallery.direction(e,gallery.trigger);
        gallery.slide()
    });
}
```

Comment: Here's the rest of the jQuery - any suggestions greatfully received.

Comment: He's new, so he simply might not know how to accept. @maxelcat , when you get an answer that answers your question, just click the checkbox next to it to accept it ;)

Comment: @maxelcat , what are you trying to use the invisible div for here? Is it supposed to be that if they run their mouse over it, then the slideshow would start? And what exactly is not working, is the mouseover event not firing off in IE?

Comment: have accpeted answers - apologies for not doing so - this forum is kinda different to what I am  used to!

Comment: Yes, the invisible div is supposed to act as a trigger to make the slide show start - if your near a left or right edge then off it goes.